# What variety of cedar is this in Puget Sound region?

Tags: identification, trees, variety-selection, cedar

Attaching three photos of of a grove of *(I think)* cedar trees, which are distinct from the common Western Red Cedar (Thuja plicata) which has a pyramid shape and uniform branches when standing alone.

These trees have a lot more 'character' to the overall shape, with gnarled branches that give it a more wind-blown look, though similar in foliage which forms in flat sprays of overlapping scales. These trees also don't seem to grow as tall as Western Red Cedar.

I wasn't successful on google looking for cedar trees that look like this, although this tree is very common in the seattle metro region.

[image: grove of cedar]
[image: cedar bark]
[image: foliage and small woody cones]

Comment: I agree with Chamaecyparis...so far.  B. nota I think has this right.  Just trying to see the differences between Thuya plicata  and Chamaecyparis the seeds seem to be the only viable way for ID.  Other than form but with a little grove of them, in no way will you be able to go by form.  Chamaecyparis...what do you think?

Comment: I think the [cones](https://oregonstate.edu/dept/ldplants/thpl7.htm) from _Thuja plicata_ look quite different, not so round as _Chamaecyparis lawsoniana_.

Answer (score 7):

Looks more cypress to me, not cedar. Maybe *[Chamaecyparis lawsoniana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaecyparis_lawsoniana)* if its from the Seattle region.

It is also called **Port Orford cedar**, this might be the reason you call it cedar?

Comment: I agree, but wanted to add some things.  We have no true ceders (_Cedrus sp._) native to the Pacific Northwest.  Most of our major native trees seem to have been misidentified by the early explored and the common names seem to have stuck with us. Port Orford cedars are actually native to Southern Oregon, though are super common up here as ornamental trees.  In addition to the cones, there's a white mark on the underside of the leaves on Port Orford cedars.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this additional information. I must admit that I have never been to the NW, yet (like to go once though). I am only known with Italian cypresses we have here in Europe, but these photos reminded me very much of a cypress species. My father used to confuse his cedar with his cypresses as well, although the big difference in my opinion.

Comment: I called it a cedar just because the foliage was similar to the common tree everyone calls cedar. I don't know a cypress from a cedar TBH.

Comment: The wiki page you referenced only shows a picture of a forest of giants, a google image search for *Chamaecyparis lawsoniana* is no help at all. I can't confirm, any links to 50 to 100 year old examples would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Bark and habit are like those of *Chamaecyparis pisifera*.

Comment: Can you provide a link to example images? The wikipedia page provides a very poor photo, though the straightness of the branches indicates this is not a match. My specimen has knurled, curvy branches.